# jQuery html() lost styling

Tags: html, css, ajax

I have HTML like this:

```html
<div class="myList"> 
  <select>
    <option value="1">Item1</option>
    <option value="2">Item2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

All the CSS is perfect. But then, when I use some AJAX, and then I do $('.myList').html(...), all the styling of the combobox disappears.

I tried some of the ideas in other threads, but none of them worked.

Comment: what kind of styling you are applying to select box?

Comment: By combobox, do you mean that this is an instance of some JS library ? in that case you most probably need to reatach/rebuild.

Comment: show your ajax response

Comment: Please add your CSS and JS

Comment: well, I found out, that the reason is exactly what Slytherin wrote... I forgot that I am using JS library to create DropDown from Select element. Now everything works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are call ($element).html you overwrite the HTML what is currently there, therefore you may actually be overwriting the HTML which sets the div (and therefore styling) use $(element).append instead, here is the API for .append() http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you add your styles with jquery, so you add your styles in the html as an attribute with style="", you can add your styles in the css and with jquery just add the classes. And when you change the html add the classes again otherwise you'll miss the styling.